# Why does the GPS module hang on my Android phone after some hours?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini, gps-tracking

I record GPX tracks using Osmand.  I have set everything so that it tracks also in the background, with the screen switched off.  After some time (usually hours), I check the GPS and must realise that it doesn't get a GPS fix anymore.  I can wait for hours under a clear sky -- no effect.  But if I stop recording, and re-start it immediately, I get a fix in a second.  What can be the cause of this?

I have created a video at http://youtu.be/sqSjm7EUgbY which demonstrates the problem: Coming and going grey and yellow bars in "GPS Status", but after a short re-start, an immediate fix!

I use Android 4.1.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S III mini.  The background plugin of Osmand 1.7.5+ is active, as is the "keep fixing in the backgroud" option of "GPS Status & Tools".  However, it doesn't matter whether the latter is installed.  The polling time in Osmand is "continuously".

The same issue occurs with some other tracking apps.  At least "GPSLogger" and "Geotag Photos" are affected.  However, I can *not* reproduce the bug with Google "My Tracks".  Maybe this is due to the fix for https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/issues/detail?id=496 but unfortunately, no details of the fix are known.

Comment: It could be the app you are using, in that case contact the developer. If it isn't happening elsewhere then I don't know, my other theory was it was overheating. Samsung devices can run VERY hot and GPS tends to be quite intensive for heat on quite a few devices. If other apps are fine, I'd say contact the developer.

Comment: As a developer I see this in my own app IpBike and basically have made the app detect the scenario and automatically stop and restart the gps which normally gets it going.  No idea about the root cause but probably some GPS firmware bug...

Comment: The device doesn't get warm.  Since at least four apps are affected, I suspect the cause deeper, i.e. in Android, the driver, or the hardware.  But Google "My Tracks" is not affected, so there seems to be a workaround.